# Cannot remote access to compute engine window instance after I set the incorrect static ip

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've a Window Server 2008 R2 instance on Google Compute Engine. I got a External IP it generated by GCE. e.g. 104.xx.xx.19.

I've set that IP (104.xx.xx.19) to a static IP, after that I cannot remote access to that Window Instance again. What should I do can let me remote access it again?

Answer (score 0):

Restart the virtual machine and try connecting again.